# Useful indices in epidemiology for assesing the performance of a country in Covid19 pandemic

Tags: covid-19, epidemiology

In my dataset I have daily observations of Covid19 data for many countries. More specifically, I have daily observations about:

- `new_cases` (New confirmed cases of COVID-19. Counts can include probable cases where reported.)
- `total_cases` (Total confirmed cases of COVID-19. Counts can include probable cases where reported.)
- `new_deaths` (New deaths attributed to COVID-19. Counts can include probable deaths where reported.)
- `total_deaths` (Total deaths attributed to COVID-19. Counts can include probable deaths, where reported.)
- `reproduction_rate` (Real-time estimate of the effective reproduction rate (R) of COVID-19. See https://github.com/crondonm/TrackingR/tree/main/Estimates-Database)
- `stringency_index` (Government Response Stringency Index: composite measure based on 9 response indicators including school closures, workplace closures, and travel bans, rescaled to a value from 0 to 100 (100 = strictest response)

for every country. So, I have 6 times series for every country of my dataset.

I want to find some indices and calculate their value for every daily observation. So far, I have found some indices and I will present them here in order to make more clear what I want.

- `Incidence Rate` I have calculated the Incidence Rate for every country and for every daily observation because it gives me information about how quickly disease occurs in a population of a country. So, if a country has high `Incidence Rate` this means that new cases occur in a fast way. So, if a country has high value on this index this means that country's performance was bad that day.
- `Cumulative Incidence Rate` I have calculated the `Cumulative Incidence Rate` for every country and for every daily observation because it gives me the probability of infection of a person who wasn't infected before. I have calculated `Cumulative Incidence Rate` because if this probability is high this means that in this country people who weren't infected before have high risk of infection that day. So, if a country has high value on this index this means that country's performance was bad that day.
- `Percentange of the population which hasn't been infected until the day d` I have calculated this index for every country and for every daily observation because if this percentage is high this means that a big part of the population before the pandemic hit has avoided Covid19 infection. So, if a country has high value on this index this means that country's performance was good that day.
- `Mortality Rate` I have calculated this index for every country and for every daily observation because if this rate is high this means that a lot of people of the population died that day. So, if a country has high value on this index this means that country's performance was bad that day.

Does anyone know indices like these which can be calculated for every daily observation and can help me assess the performance of every country every day?

Comment: All of these measures have systematic reporting biases by country, so you won't get anywhere without a far more sophisticated analysis, and even then I think the estimates will be questionable. I'd also strongly question the idea that this could possibly be measured *daily*, even with perfect data - the causes of a case or death are not attributable to activity on any given day.

Comment: One example of the reporting biases @BryanKrause mentioned is the spikes in deaths very commonly seen on Mondays. They occur because most reporting agencies don't report on the weekends, so all deaths over a weekend get reported as deaths on Monday.